# How to add Twitter to Notification Center in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, notifications, twitter

I just got a new 4S and am not seeing notifications pop-ups from Twitter.  I'm using the Twitter for iPhone app.  How can I enable new tweets in notification center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New tweets in Twitter can't be added to the notification centre, thankfully. It will only notify you in the notification centre if your mentioned or receive a direct message.

The settings for the Twitter notifications can be found in `Settings` -> `Notification Centre`

[image: Twitter Notification Centre]

Also make sure you have your Twitter set up correctly under `Settings` -> `Twitter` after installing the Twitter app.

[image: Twitter Settings]

Comment: Twitter is not listed under Settings -> Notification Centre... Why would that be?

Comment: @cellu Have you launched the Twitter app since getting your new phone yet?

Answer (score 1):

Go under Settings and look for the Notifications app and you should see listed there all the apps you have in your iOS. Select your Twitter account. You should see something similar or the same as the screen shown below. From there you can configure your Twitter for Notifications Center. Hope this helps.

[image]